# In azure, using service i could get image but can only see in preview as direct image

Tags: angular, azure, azure-storage, dreamfactory

In azure, using service i could get image but can only see in preview as direct image but it is not in the format of base64, or etc.

but i need image in json format

i am giving below service in angular

[I call service like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHpVr.png)

[i am getting response in preview not in base64, blob and json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swzoG.png)

i need to catch the image and return to angular service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch an image from Azure storage and want it to be form of base64 or json format. You can do below of two things

1. While inserting the image into storage itself , try to convert into base64 and then store it. You can refer to this [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582878/successfully-saving-base64-image-to-azure-blob-storage-but-blob-image-always-bro/39590768)
2. Convert the image to Base64 once you fetch it from storage before you can return it to angular service. You can refer to this [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369945/converting-image-from-azure-blob-storage-to-base64) or [this blog](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3493/preview-azure-blob-image-from-base64-encoded-string-in-angularjs) for reference.